# Excel VBA HTML Import Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been using the below vba from another thread and have modified it to allow html vs txt.

When it imports the HTML it works fine but the html is spread out over multiple rows and not contained to one cell.

Is there a way to restrict the html to once cell only?

I need all the html to be in one cell as I need to process about 500 html files regularly and i just require it to be in individual cells.

Any help appreciated.

```
Sub ImportTXTFiles()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant, txtfile As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
             (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.html), *.html", _
              MultiSelect:=True, Title:="HTML Files to Open")

With ActiveSheet

    For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen

        importrow = 1 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ' IMPORT DATA FROM TEXT FILE
        With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & txtfile, _
          Destination:=.Cells(importrow, 1))
         
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "$"
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With


    Next txtfile

    For Each qt In .QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Successfully imported text files!", vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL IMPORT"

Set FSO = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub ImportTXTFiles()
 Dim FSO As Object, txtStr As Object, strText As String, sh As Worksheet
 Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant, txtfile As Variant, importrow As Long

 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet
 
 txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
             (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.html), *.html", _
              MultiSelect:=True, Title:="HTML Files to Open")

    For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen
        importrow = 1 + sh.cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set txtStr = FSO.OpenTextFile(txtfile)
            strText = txtStr.ReadAll
        txtStr.Close
        If Len(strText) <= 32000 Then
            sh.cells(importrow, 1).Value = strText:
        Else
            MsgBox txtfile & " size exceeds the limit of 32000 digits..."
        End If

    Next txtfile

 MsgBox "Successfully imported text files!", vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL IMPORT"

 Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

It checks the limit of a cell string size (32k characters) and rise a message for such a case... If necessary, it can split the string in portions of 32k and paste in the next cells, marking in B:B 1, 2 ... x portion numbers...

Comment: @Bob Rodgers: Glad I could help!